# Suppose $Y\subset X$ and $X,Y$ are connected and $A,B$ form separation for $X-Y$ then, prove that $Y\cup A$ and $Y\cup B$ are connected

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Question is :

Suppose $Y\subset X$ and $X,Y$ are connected and $A,B$ form separation for $X-Y$ then, Prove that  $Y\cup A$ and $Y\cup B$ are connected.

What i have tried is :

Suppose $Y\cup A$ has  separation say $C\cup D$ then all i could see is that

Either $Y\subset C$ or $Y\subset D$ as $Y$ is connected and $
C\cup D$ is separation for a subset that contains $Y$.

Without loss of generality we could assume $Y\subset C$

As $Y\cup A=C\cup D$ and $Y\subset C$  i can say $D\subset A$ (I do not know how does this help)

I have $X-Y=A\cup B$ with $A\cap B=\emptyset$

I have not used connectedness of $X$ till now, So i thought of using that and end up with following :

$X-Y=A\cup B\Rightarrow X=Y\cup A\cup B=(Y\cup A)\cup (Y\cup B)$

I do not know what to conclude from this...

I would be thankful if some one can help me by giving some "hints"

Thank you

Answer (score 8):

As $A,B$ form a separation for $X-Y$ and $X$ is connected, $Y$ must be non-empty.
You suppose that $Y\cup A$ has a separation $C\cup D$. Then $Y$, being connected, is a subset of $C$

Now $A$ is clopen in $X-Y$, that means there are sets $U$ open and $K$ closed, such that $U-Y=K-Y=A$. You know that $D\subseteq A$ is clopen in $Y\cup A$. Can you show that $D$ is open in $U$ and closed in $K$?

Comment: Second paragraph is confusing me... could you please edit it a bit...

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik: Which sentence confuses you?

Comment: As $A$ is open in $X-Y$ I have a open set $U$ in $X$ such that $A=U\cap (X-Y)=U-Y$.. As $A$ is closed in $X-Y$ I have a closed set $K$ in $X$ such that $A=K\cap (X-Y)=K-Y$.. this i understood.. after that i am not able to grasp the idea..

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik: $D$ is a subset of $A$ (since $Y\subseteq C$), and it is clopen in $A\cup Y$, since $A, B$ form a separation of $A\cup Y$. But then $A$ is also clopen in every subset of $A\cup Y$, so it is clopen in $U$ and in $K$.

Comment: I should have been more careful when saying "I did not understood"... I realize everything is fine but I do not know how is it so natural :O ... Hoping to see some illuminating way :O

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik: But you are able to finish the proof from here, aren't you? So is your question about how to get the idea, and how to approach such a problem?

Comment: Yes.. I have finished it.... but how should i get that idea is my question :O

Comment: Well, I should say I had already solved this problem some time ago, then forgot the proof so I had to solve it again, but it wasn"t entirely new to me. When I deal with such a problem I usually draw a picture and draw into it the sets that I can think of, in order to see how they relate. Here it was a large disk $X$, a smaller disk $Y$ within $X$, and two lines from the outer circle to the inner circle which you can think of separating $X-Y$ into $A$ and $B$. Then I separated $A\cup Y$ into $D$ and $C$ where $D$ was just a subset of $A$ ... (to be continued)

Comment: ... Then I drew the sets $U$ and $K$, corresponding to the fact that $A$ was clopen in $X-Y$. At this point I could have drawn to other sets corresponding to the $D$ (or $C$) being clopen in $A\cup Y$, but that would have added to the mess, and would have allowed for to many intersection, differences, and so on... At this point, you should stop drawing and remember what you wanted to show. Namely find a set which is clopen in $X$, to get a contradiction. Now there are many candidates for this set, and it's somehow trial and error, but it helps to recall that a set which is open ...

Comment: ... in another open set is open in the entire space, and from my picture I could "see" that $D$ was a subset of $U$, and that $U$ was a subset of $A\cup Y$, where $D$ was open in. So that's how I solved this problem. I couldn't do this without having a picture, usually in $\Bbb R^2$, lol. Hope that helps.

Comment: Why do you define $A$ is clopen in $X-Y$ as there are open set $H$ and closed $K$ such that $H-Y=K-Y=A$. I mean, using this definition will prevent us from defining clopen set in $Y\cup A$. Why not say: $A$ is clopen set in $T$ if it's both closed and open? I find your definition very confusing in fact.

Comment: @MathsLover: Actually, I don't define anything here. $A$ is clopen in $X-Y$ if it's both open and closed in $X-Y$. And this implies the existence of the sets $U$ and $K$.

Comment: Ok. Now, I've finished the proof :). First of all: $U=A\cup S$ where $S\subset Y$. And $D$ is open of $Y\cup A $ and $U\subset Y\cup A$ so $D$ is open of the subspace $U$ of $Y\cup A$. but $U$ is open set of $X$ so $D$ is open set of $X$. Similar argument establish that $D$ is closed in $X$(by showing that $D$ is closed in $K$), contradicting that $X$ is connected. Is this argument right?

Comment: @MathsLover: Yes, that argument is right :)

Answer (score 6):

Continuing with your argument, We can prove that $B \cup C$ and $D$ form the partition of $X$.(Assuming your conclusion that $D \subset A$).

We have $X = (B \cup C) \cup D$.

$C$ and $D$ form separation of $Y \cup A$. So, using theorem (23.1), no limit point of $C$ is in $D$. Similarly, no limit point of $B$ is in $D$ since $D \subset A$ and $A$ and $B$ form separation of $X-Y$. From this, we can easily say that no limit point of $B \cup C$ is in $D$ i.e. Every limit point of $B \cup C$ wrt $X$ is in $B \cup C$. So, $B \cup C$ is closed in $X$ and $D$ is open in $X$.

Now, use a similar argument that, no limit point of $D$ is  in $B \cup C$ implying that $D$ is closed in $X$ and $B\cup C$ is open in X. Hence, $B \cup C$ and $D$ are $\textit{clopen}$ in $X$ and form partition of $X$.

Answer (score 0):

We have $X \setminus Y = A \cup B$. On the other hand as $Y \subset X$, then $Y \cup (X \setminus Y) = X \cup Y = X$. Hence, of the equality $Y \cup (X \setminus Y) = Y \cup (A \cup B)$, we have that $X = (Y \cup A) \cup (Y \cup B)$. And since $X$ is connected, this last union is connected.
You can apply a theorem that says the following: the union of a collection of connected subspaces of $X$ that have a point in common is connected.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A',B'$ be open in $X$ with $A'\cap (A\cup B)=A$ and $B'\cap (A\cup B)=B.$ [ So $A'\cap B'\subset Y.$ ]

Suppose $Y\cup A\subset C'\cup D'$ where $C',D'$ are open in X, with $C'\cap (Y\cup A),\; D'\cap (Y\cup A)$ being disjoint.$\quad$ [ So $D'\cap C'\subset B$ . ]

Then $C'\cap Y,\, D'\cap Y$ are open in $Y$ and disjoint, and cover $Y.$ Since $Y$ is connected, one of them, say $D'\cap Y,$ is empty.

So $Y\subset C'.$ We show that $Y\cup A$ is connected by showing that $A$ is also a subset of $C',$ as follows:

Let $E'=A'\cap D'$ and let $F'=C'\cup B'.$

We have  $E'\cap C'=A'\cap (D'\cap C')\subset A'\cap B=\emptyset.$

We have $E'\cap B'=D'\cap (A'\cap B')\subset  D'\cap Y=\emptyset.$

Therefore $E',F'$ are disjoint.

We have $Y\cup B\subset C'\cup B\subset C'\cup B'=F'.$

We have $A=(A\cap D')\cup (A\cap C')\subset (A'\cap D')\cup (A\cap C')=E'\cup (A\cap C')\subset E'\cup F'.$

Therefore, since $X=(Y\cup B)\cup A,$ we have  $E'\cup F'=X.$

Now we have $E'=\emptyset$ because (i) $E',F'$ are disjoint and open in $X$ with $E'\cup F'=X,$ and $X$ is connected, so one of $E', F'$ is empty, and (ii) $Y\subset F'$ and $Y$ is not empty, otherwise $X=A\cup B=A'\cup B'$ would be a disconnection of $X.$

Hence $X=F'.$ So $A=A\cap F'=A\cap (C'\cup B')=(A\cap C')\cup (A\cap B')=(A\cap C')\cup \emptyset \subset C'$ as desired.

Comment: I got  the idea for $E',F'$ by drawing a picture.