# $Y \subset X$ , $X,Y$ be connected (not both) and $A,B$ be a separation of $X \setminus Y$ ; then $Y \cup A$ , $ Y \cup B$ are connected?

Tags: general-topology, soft-question, connectedness

Let $Y \subset X$ , $X,Y$ be connected and $A,B$ be a separation of $X \setminus Y$ ; then I know that $Y \cup A$ , $ Y \cup B$ are  connected  . Can we drop either of the connected assumptions of $X$ , or $Y$ ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Suppose $Y\subset X$ and $X,Y$ are connected and $A,B$ form separation for $X-Y$ then, prove that $Y\cup A$ and $Y\cup B$ are connected](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/736457/suppose-y-subset-x-and-x-y-are-connected-and-a-b-form-separation-for-x-y)

Answer (score 1):

I'm giving a solution here with some details omitted.

Note that it suffices to show (by symmetry) that $Y \cup A$ is connected. Suppose not, then it can be written as a disjoint clopen union (non-trivially) of say $U$ and $V$. 
By connectedness of $Y$ one of them, say $U$ must miss $Y$, and then one checks that $U$ is clopen in $A$. As $A$ is clopen in $X \setminus Y$, $U$ would then be clopen in $X \setminus Y$ and thus in $X$, contradicting its connectedness.

Comment: If $U$  is clopen in $X \setminus Y$ , why $U$ must be clopen in $X$ ?

Comment: Why does $A$ being clopen in $X-Y$ imply $U$ is clopen in $X$? By that logic, wouldn't $A$ be clopen in $X$ as well?